# Che cosa vuol dire "indementito"? Qual è la differenza con "demente"?

Tags: word-meaning, difference, adjectives

Nel racconto *Argon* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Morí piú che ottantenne nel 1928, assistita da un coro di vicine di casa scarmigliate, nerovestite e **indementite** come lei, condotte da una megera che si chiamava Madama Scílimberg: fra i tormenti del blocco renale, la nonna sorvegliò la Scílimberg fino al suo ultimo respiro, per timore che trovasse il maftèkh (la chiave) nascosto sotto il materasso, e le portasse via i mañòd e i hafassím (i gioielli, che peraltro risultarono poi tutti falsi).

Non ho trovato il termine "indementito" né il verbo "indementire" su nessun dizionario. Una ricerca su Google, però, ne dà parecchie occorrenze. Qual è il suo significato?

Quando ho letto questa parola, ho pensato che potesse avere qualcosa a che vedere con "demente". Ma poi ho ragionato che, se fosse stato così, l'autore avrebbe usato l'aggettivo "dementi" in questo testo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questa parola deriva da "demente" ([prendo dal vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/demente/)):

> **demènte** agg. e s. m. e f. [dal lat. *demens -entis*, comp. di de- con valore privativo e mens «mente»]. – Affetto da demenza: *reparto per dementi; un vecchio, una vecchia demente*. Nel linguaggio com., pazzo, privo di senno, stolto, anche come titolo d’ingiuria o spreg.: taci, sei un povero demente!

Quindi la parola letteralmente significa. "diventate/rese dementi".

Guardando [questo elenco](http://wwwdata.unibg.it/dati/corsi/24169/60754-Lista_morfemi_italiano_Facchi.pdf) siamo nel campo dei "morfemi verbalizzatori":

> **in-** (e allomorfi **inn-/im-/ir-/il-**) : prefisso verbalizzatore.
>
> camera → incamerare
>
> [...]
>
> brutto → imbruttire

quindi

demente →  indementire → indementito

Nel brano in questione si parla di persone molto anziane, per cui immagino stiamo parlando di demenza senile, di persone che, per via dell'età avanzata, non ci stanno più molto con la testa.

Come fatto notare nei commenti da @Charo, l'uso di "indementite" anzichè del semplice aggettivo "dementi" sta a indicare una sorta di processo che si è sviluppato nel tempo, non di una condizione fissa delle persone di cui si parla.

Comment: Non conosco tutto il contesto, immagino stiamo parlando di demenza senile visto che si parla di persone molto anziane. Modifico la risposta.

Comment: Il racconto non spiega niente di piú di queste vicine, ma da quel "come lei" (una signora "piú che ottantenne"), più che "impazzite", mi sembra più plausibile che fossero affette da qualche tipo demenza a causa dell'età.

Comment: In effetti hai ragione, posso levare la parte di equivalenza con impazzito

Comment: Immagino che si l'autore usa "indementite" e non "dementi" è per dare a intendere che tempo prima, quando erano più giovani, non erano dementi, ma che lo sono diventate a causa dell'età, no?

Comment: @Charo secondo me hai perfettamente ragione.

Comment: Veramente avevo pensato che il termine potesse avere qualcosa a che vedere con "demente", ma avevo ragionato che, se fosse stato così, l'autore avrebbe semplicemente usato "dementi". Non mi ero accorta che potesse esserci questa sfumatura di significato che fa questo termine diverso di "demente". Forse il problema è che le mie lingue hanno l'aggettivo "demente" / "dement", ma non hanno niente di equivalente a "indementire" o "indementito".

Comment: Solo un piccola nota per dire che nella narrativa è possibile che un autore, un’autrice, “inventi” delle parole usando i consueti fenomeni di formazione delle parole. In questo senso, uno dei meccanismi più usati è proprio il prefisso in- + un aggettivo o un verbo, a indicare “diventato/a o diventare”. Michele Mari, per restare nella letteratura italiana contemporanea, usa moltissimo questa tecnica.

Comment: Va bene, @Benedetta. L'unico è che in spagnolo esiste lo stesso aggettivo, "demente", e in catalano uno di molto simile, "dement", ma non riesco a immaginare un verbo in queste lingue che possa significare "diventare demente": per esempio, "enloquecer" (da "loco") e "embogir" (da "boig") significano "diventare pazzo". Ma "indementecer" o "endementir" non mi suonano per niente bene: parlando in catalano, per fare un esempio, credo che se dicesse a qualcuno "aquella persona ha endementit" non mi capirebbe nessuno. Per cui, quello che chiedo nella domanda non era per me tanto ovvio.

Comment: A differenza di quanto capita nelle lingue di @Charo, il termine "indementito" in italiano è perfettamente e immediatamente comprensibile da tutti. Oltre all'idea del divenire demente, Levi, sempre precisissimo nella scelte lessicali, lo ha probabilmente usato anche per uniformità con i due termini precedenti: la descrizione del testo è molto più potente dell'alternativa "scarmigliate, vestite di nero e diventate dementi".

Comment: Va bene, @enrico: diciamo che è completamente comprensibile da tutti gli italiani (cioè, non "da tutti" :).

Comment: @Charo, la mia era solo una piccola aggiunta :) Mi sembra interessante capire i fenomeni all’origine di certe parole che possono sembrarci strane… (Non intendevo in alcun modo dire che il significato della parola sia ovvio).